# Convert QVector to std::vector without copying

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qvector

Is there any way to convert [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) to [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) without copying (without using toStdVector or fromStdVector functions)?

using [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) causes compile error.

Comment: No there's no way to do that. These are completely different classes.

Comment: This sounds like it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve in this situation?

Comment: Element-wise move will work, if the corresponding type is movable.

Comment: @MrEricSir, I'm using a library which works on QVector and one another which works on std::vector and I don't want to copy my large size vector each time working with it.

Comment: @Tulon, I want a way to do it quickly without performance loss, e.g. if there was a way to point the data of QVector to data of std::vector with O(1) operation, it was optimum solution.

Comment: @abdolahS There is no way to do it in O(1). Element-wise move would be O(N).